Can't resolve System.Windows.Control.Image from being created instead of System.Drawing.Image
I'm working on moving a C# program into a WPF application and in order to export files from records I need to use the following code:
// Construct _imgfiles from the records
string _imgfile = _maindest + "Images\\" + _pageseq.ToString("0000") + ".tif";
if ((_recpage.FileType == FileType.ImageFile) && (_recpage.ImageType == ImageFileType.TIFF))
{
    // Copy the record into it's designated directory
    File.Copy(_recpage.FileLocation, _imgfile);
    totalRecords++;
}
else if ((_recpage.FileType == FileType.ImageFile) && (_recpage.ImageType == ImageFileType.JPEG || _recpage.ImageType == ImageFileType.BMP))
{
    Image _tmpimg = Image.FromFile(_recpage.FileLocation);
    _tmpimg.Save(_imgfile, _conn.EncoderInfo, _conn.ImgEncParams);
    _totalpages++;
}

I run into an error at the following line:
Image _tmpimg = Image.FromFile(_recpage.FileLocation);

Where the 'Image' being created is not one of System.Drawing.Image that I need in order to access the 'FromFile' function but one from System.Windows.Control.Image. Which is still needed in other areas of the code, so taking it out would not be an appropriate fix.
I tried calling it directly:
System.Drawing.Image _tmpimg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(_recpage.FileLocation);
With no luck, as well as Aliasing the namespace which didn't do any good either:
using DrawingImage = System.Drawing.Image;
DrawingImage _tmpimg = DrawingImage.FromFile(_recpage.FileLocation);
I had read in another question that System.Drawing.Image shouldn't be used in WPF apps however that question was related to bitmaps and was over 7 years ago, so I don't know how relevant it is here. Any help?

There's a distinct lack of error messages in this question. If you're asking for help with an error then providing the error message should be a no-brainer. Regardless, if this is a WPF project then the assembly in which the System.Drawing.Image type is declared will not be referenced by default, so you'd have to add that reference. How exactly you do that depends on what framework you're targeting, which you also haven't told us. You should read the documentation for the appropriate framework.

@jmcilhinney I didn't think the errors it was giving me would be of any use. 'Error (active) CS0117 'Image' does not contain a definition for 'FromFile' \WpfApp1\MainWindow.xaml.cs'
I did read the documentation, I'm inexperienced

And what about when you fully qualified the name, i.e. used System.Drawing.Image? Did that give you the same error message? I wouldn't expect it to.

The documentation will tell you which assembly the type is defined in and, if relevant, which NuGet package. You select the appropriate framework version and the documentation changes accordingly. If you're targeting .NET Framework then you'll need to reference the appropriate assembly directly. If you're targeting .NET Core (including .NET 5 and later) then you'll need to install the appropriate NuGet package.

The Image class in WPF is a UI element (or control) class, similar to the PictureBox in WinWorms. WinForms code that loads a System.Drawing.Image from a file (i.e. a bitmap) would have to be replaced by code that loads a WPF System.Windows.Media.ImageSource. One way to do so would be to create a BitmapImage from a FileStream.

If you port code from WinForms to WPF, you should get rid of System.Drawing.Image, because it can't be used directly in a WPF UI.

@Clemens, my impression was that there was no desire to use it in the UI, although I could be wrong. It seems to be that the OP wants to open an image file and then save it elsewhere. If there's a simple way to do that with WPF types then that would be the best solution, I think. I'm not familiar enough to know whether there is such a way.

@jmcilhinney Well, File.Copy would obviously always work. If you need a different encoding, there is the BitmapEncoder and derived classes, which save to a Stream. Besides that, the question says "...but one from System.Windows.Control.Image. Which is still needed in other areas of the code...", so we may assume the UI does display images.

@Clemens, "we may assume the UI does display images". Yeah, but not this image, based on the code provided. If you can advise a means to achieve what the code provided is intended to do using WPF types, that's probably what you ought to recommend. I'd ask the OP if that's what they want to do and then you could provide an answer or at least a direct pointer about how to do that.

@Esai using DrawingImage = System.Drawing.Image; may not work because DrawingImage is another WPF type. Just use a different alias name.

Besides that, please let us know if you are interested in replacing the WinForms code with the appropriate WPF code.

"I had read in another question that System.Drawing.Image shouldn't be used in WPF apps"  - as GDI+ and WPF are both Windows-only libraries (not considering libgdiplus on Linux before .NET 7), it's not inherently wrong using Drawing.Image in a WPF app if it's not meant to displayed directly. Sometimes it can be beneficial, eg. performance, more direct memory management (disposability), etc.

jmcilhinney is right.
To use System.Drawing.Image in WPF and successfully run System.Drawing.Image temp = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("Image address"); you need to set the following.
In the WPF APP(.NET Framework)
you need to reference System.Drawing:
References->Add Reference->Assemblies->Framework-> Find System.Drawing and add
In In WPF Application
You need to install System.Drawing.Common via NuGet
